# Programming style and number of variables and correct formula for the program and to test the programm for a lot of conditions

Tags: c, variables, formula

Look at the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAX 5   /* Defines percentage of tax for the year */

int main(void)
{
    float amount;
    float taxes;
    float total;

    printf("Enter the value of the amount: ");
    scanf("%f", &amount);

    taxes = (TAX / amount); 
    total = amount + taxes;

    printf("The total amount is: $%.2f",total);
    return 0;
}
```

this has to calculate interest of 5% for the given amount , I am replacing the formula taxes to:
taxes = (TAX / amount) * 100
but still when i enter input i,e amount less than 50 i get stupid meaningless output, what is the right formula, why cant i figure out what to do for smaller input, can anyone let me know the right way of doing this.

I also want to ask about style, i put out the program for this problem, just tell me what kind of programs are better, should i minimize number of variables or should i directly calculate the value for tax in the defined TAX macro itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAX (5 / amount) * 100  /* Defines percentage of tax for the year */

int main(void)
{
    float amount;
    float total;

    printf("Enter the value of the amount: ");
    scanf("%f", &amount);

    total = amount + TAX

    printf("The total amount is: $%.2f",total);
    return 0;
}
```

Look at this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAX 5   /* Defines percentage of tax for the year */

int main(void)
{
    float amount;
    float taxes;
    float total;

    printf("Enter the value of the amount: ");
    scanf("%f", &amount);

    taxes = (TAX / amount) * 100;
    total = amount + taxes;

    printf("The tax on your amount is: $%f",total);
    return 0;
}
```

And what are the other better ways to write this, how should i arrive at a formula, I still feel its really simple i dont know why i am messing up. I have solved a lot of exercise from the book C programming b KN King, in fact almost 90% of them, but today i thought of revising all the concepts again and i got stuck on this thing.

Once again the question is: A program to calculate interest rate for the give amount, the given rate is 5%, not difficult right, try for smaller amount values.

Thanks in advance for all those who offer suggestion and solution.

Comment: The macro uses integer constants to compute a percentage.  Seems like a risky approach.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(TAX / 100) * amount` ?

Comment: Don't use `float` without a very good reason to avoid `double`. "The teacher said so" is not a good reason until after you tried to dissuade her.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem with your formula is that in order to calculate tax, you should be taking the tax percentage **as a decimal** and **multiply** it times the amount.  Therefore, you need to take the 5%, and divide it by 100 to make it a decimal number.

As far as style, your first example is the most readable, with variable names that "tell a story" and show exactly what it is that you are doing.  I would eliminate the `tax` variable though, unless you are using it for something else since it is really not needed.  The second one is "bad" because it *assumes* that there is a variable called `amount`, which may or may not be there if you reuse the macro (and if you don't reuse it, why is it a macro in the first place?).  You could use a macro that takes an argument, but then you should call it CALCULATE_TAX or something, so that it is immediately obvious that it is calculating something, and not simply a constant.

Anyway, here is how I would do it:

```
#define TAX_RATE 0.05   /* Defines percentage of tax for the year as 5% (0.05) */

int main(void)
{
    double amount;
    double total;

    // Get the amount, there should be some error checking on the input though:
    printf("Enter the value of the amount: ");
    scanf("%f", &amount);

    // Calculate the total amount, with taxes and print it:
    total = amount + TAX_RATE * amount;
    printf("The total amount is: $%.2f",total);

    return 0;
}
```